# How to create a nested Dictionary/List mixed with int and string keys while 1 key being dynamic addable int key in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dictionary, nested

Does anyone know how to achieve a dictionary/list/array in the form in such 
(1 key being numeric based index and 1-2 keys being text based key and holds 1 value) 
while maintaining decent capabilities to sort/remove/add/search for its key

its list form should look something similar to

```
MyList[0]["movie"]["name"] =  "terminator 1";
MyList[0]["movie"]["year"] =  "1992";

MyList[1]["movie"]["name"] =  "terminator 2";
MyList[1]["movie"]["year"] =  "1993";
```

however, with the ability to add/push it dynamically without having indicate your maximum array size or input and state your numeric index [0] or [1]

in a way which we can dynamically add/push in something similar to

```
    MyList.add("movie", "name", "terminator 1");
  ` MyList.add("movie", "name", "terminator 2");
```

and at the same time having the ability to specifying keys and assign its value like:
(for the purpose of later adding more information)

```
MyList[0]["movie"]["year"] = "1992";
MyList[0]["movie"]["year"] = "1993";
```

I've tried declaring in various nested Dictionary<> and List<>  but unable to find a solution through trial and error. if there is any other simple or more appropriate way to hold values which can dynamically hold multiple numeric keys and string keys, please share links and references as well.  thanks for the effort

Comment: You are probably better off creating a POCO class called `Movie` and giving it properties `id`, `year`, `name` etc... then just create a `List<Movie>()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer! After some effort trying to use POCO by organizing the variables into properties and assigning them to a list<>, it seems to work well and feels a lot more organized and neat.